# Winsocket Timeout for send operation

Tags: visual-c++, tcp, winsockets

I have written a TCP Socket application in vc++ 2008. I want 'send' operation to be timed out if it takes more than x seconds. For that I tried using

`char *optValue = "5000";

setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, optValue, sizeof(optValue));`

It returns success, but 'send' didn't behave as expected. Then tried with

`tv.tv_sec = 10;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
FD_SET(accept_socket, &write_mask);
select(socket, (fd_set *)0, &write_mask, (fd_set *)0, &tv);`

Still 'send' is not behaving according to the timeout value set.
Please check is it the right way to do?

Comment: Are you sure that the setsocket argument has to be passed as a string? The function accepts a char pointer, but this is just used as a pointer to "something".

Comment: I changed it to integer, and used char pointer to that. (As told in Answer1 below). Still problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

The `setsockopt`, while accepting a `char *` doesn't actually want the values as strings. You should pass the value as a pointer to an integer, typecasted to `char *`:

```
int optValue = 5000;
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (const char *) &optValue, sizeof(optValue));
```

PS. Your usage of `sizeof` does not do what you think it does. It returns the size of the *pointer*, not what it points to.

Comment: I tried the same way as you suggested. Still its not timing out.